# Shift across registers efficiently

Tags: assembly, x86-64, bit-shift, extended-precision

How can I efficiently fill the most significant bit of a register with the least significant bit of another register in x64-Assembly. The Intended use is efficient division of a 128bit value by two (essentially a cross-register shift).

```
RDX:RAX (result after MUL-Operation)
```

Comment: Look at compiler output for `__uint128_t` from GCC or clang `-O3`.  They should know how to use `shrd` / `shr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `shrd` instruction to shift a bit from the src into the destination:

```
shrd rax, rdx, 1   ; shift a bit from bottom of RDX into top of RAX
shr  rdx, 1        ; and then shift the high half
; rdx:rax is shifted one bit to the right
```

Alternatively, use a `shr` and a `rcr` instruction, but note that `rcr` is multiple uops so this is slower on most CPUs:

```
shr rdx, 1          ; shift LSB of rdx into cf
rcr rax, 1          ; shift CF into rax
```

Comment: @PeterCordes I used to think it was only slow with immediates other than 1.  On AMD, it's a single µop instruction with shift amount 1.  On Intel it's surprisingly slow (except on PPro?)

Comment: Oh, I forgot AMD had efficient rcr by 1.  Intel renames CF separately from the rest (SPAZO), but RCR writes some but not all of the flags, including some from both groups.

Comment: Since mul sets overflow and carry flags whenever the upper register is != 0, can this be used in all cases if we just shift by 1 bit?

Comment: @ValentinMetz Yes.  The `shrd` instruction does not care about how the flags are set and neither does `shr`.